# Delete pages using fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I would like to remove some pages from my PDF created using fpdf library,

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Is there any function to remove the page. I am not familiar with FPDF.

Comment: FPDF does not allow for deleting pages. You might try TCPDF which has the function deletePage(page_no) allowing you to remove a page.

Comment: I assume that `unset($pdf->pages[pageNum])` should work, though not tested. After deletion you have to reindex the array to make array indexes to fit the real page numbers. The index of first page is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/). Get out of the mentality of "deleting" a page. Instead, view it as "not inserting" a page. Let's say I want to skip pages 3, 15, 17, and 22. Here's how you do it:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('document.pdf');

//  Array of pages to skip -- modify this to fit your needs
$skipPages = [3,15,17,22];

//  Add all pages of source to new document
for( $pageNo=1; $pageNo<=$pageCount; $pageNo++ )
{
    //  Skip undesired pages
    if( in_array($pageNo,$skipPages) )
        continue;

    //  Add page to the document
    $templateID = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateID);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateID);
}

$pdf->Output();
```

Please note that I didn't include a lot of things you could do with FPDI, including determining the orientation of the page. I also skipped out on some error checking for the sake of simplicity. View this as a template to work off of, not as the final code, because it is ultimately just a quick skeleton.